# Javascript/Jquery Super Scrollorama Navigation Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, superscrollorama

On a Wordpress site I am currently working on, my client wanted the different sections of the front page to slide up from the bottom and cover up the previous section, like a wipe or slide transition. Using super scrollorama found here: http://johnpolacek.github.com/superscrollorama/, I managed to achieve the desired result.

Next, I needed to create a navigation menu on the front page only. I did so, and set anchors at various different points on the pages. I also used the scrollTo library for scolling animations when I click the nav menu links. However, there are a number of problems I have encountered:

- When at the top and I click "showcase", it brings me down to the showcase section, but the products section (the div right after it) is overlapping it.
- Other divs seems to have the same problem of the following divs overlapping the current one
- I can only navigate forwards. When I try to go backwards, it won't (except for "Home")
- I thought it might have something to do with the CSS "top" property of the divs, so I tried resetting them every time the click function kicked in, but it didn't work. So I removed it for the time being.
- Currently set the javascript to prevent the default action of scrolling to the anchors and instead setting it to scroll to the actual divs themselves. However, I'm still having the same issues.

**EDIT:** I solved all of the above problems, but now a new problem has arisen. If you scroll through the site, then resize the browser window and scroll back up, you'll notice that a bit of the bottom gets cut off. I looked at the superscrollorama page and it has the same problem. I was hoping that someone knows how to fix this.

Here is the site I am currently working on: http://breathe.simalam.ca/

Here is the javascript for the scrolling:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.home-link').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(window).scrollTo(0, 1000, {queue:true});
});
jQuery('.showcase-link').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(window).scrollTo('#showcase_content', 1000, {queue:true});
});
jQuery('.products-link').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(window).scrollTo('#products_content', 1000, {queue:true});

});
jQuery('.about-link').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(window).scrollTo('#about_content', 1000, {queue:true});

});
jQuery('.locator-link').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(window).scrollTo('#locator_content', 1000, {queue:true});

});
jQuery('.contact-link').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(window).scrollTo('#contact_content', 1000, {queue:true});

}); });
```

scrollorama code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#wrapper').css('display','block');
    var controller = $.superscrollorama();
    var pinDur = 4000;  /* set duration of pin scroll in pixels */

    // create animation timeline for pinned element
    var pinAnimations = new TimelineLite();
    pinAnimations
    .append([
        TweenMax.to($('#showcase'), .5, {css:{top:0}})
    ], .5)
    .append([
        TweenMax.to($('#products'), .5, {css:{top:0}})
    ], .5)
    .append([
        TweenMax.to($('#about'), .5, {css:{top:0}})
    ], .5)
    .append([
        TweenMax.to($('#locator'), .5, {css:{top:0}})
    ], .5)
    .append([
        TweenMax.to($('#contact'), .5, {css:{top:0}})
    ], .5)
    .append(TweenMax.to($('#pin-frame-unpin'), .5, {css:{top:'100px'}}));


    controller.pin($('#examples-pin'), pinDur, {
        anim:pinAnimations, 
        onPin: function() {
            $('#examples-pin').css('height','100%');
        }, 
        onUnpin: function() {
            $('#examples-pin').css('height','2000px');
        }
    }); });
```

All of the section divs are inside a parent div. The section divs all have a height, width, and top of 100%.

The parent div containing all of these section divs are as follows:

```
#examples-pin { 
 position: relative; /* relative positioning for transitions to work? */
 width: 101%; /* max width */
 height: 2000px; /* height of 2000px for now */
 overflow: hidden; /* hide the overflow for transitions to work */
 margin-bottom: -200px; /* negative bottom margin */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In summary,  pushFollowers: false for all pins and manually spacing via a div and padding after the pinned element was the solution.

It seems like this issue is going to be fixed in the next version of superscrollorama.  I would look at https://github.com/johnpolacek/superscrollorama/issues  issue 94 they have demo code of their new one coming out.